# How to start a new JVM from code with long classpath

Tags: java, scala, jvm, classpath

I found how to start a simple JVM from code in scala, but the answers assume a short classpath. I'm trying to make a JVM to run an isolated spark program so that I have quite a lot of things going on in my classpath.

Understandably I get a 
`java.io.IOException: CreateProcess error=206, The filename or extension is too long`
Caused by a `java.io.IOException: Cannot run program "path/to/java": CreateProcess error=206, The filename or extension is too long`

If I were to run it from IntelliJ I'd just shorten the classpath. How can I do that (or something similar) from code? (Preferably scala, but if not possible Java is also fine).

PS: My classpath is `37311` characters long

Comment: Is the classpath your problem as in `-classpath VALUE;VALUE;VALUE;...` or is `java`  executable nested so deep that this is an issue? Title suggest the former but text suggest the latter.

Comment: I have to wonder how on earth ending up with a 37K classpath is even possible

Comment: @MateuszKubuszok The classpath is the issue if I start the process with -classpath abc it "starts" but obviously fails immediately, but the java runtime starts.

Comment: You can try putting it into CLASSPATH environment variable.